# How to disassemble the last few instructions of a Native API in Windbg?

Tags: windbg

I want to disassemble the last few instructions of a Native API in Windbg. How do I go about doing this?

For instance, I am in Kernel Mode in Windbg and want to disassemble the last few instructions of the KiSystemService API, how do I do that?

Also, if there is a way to view the size of the API, it would be possible to view the last instruction.

u nt!KiSystemService

Gives me around 10 Lines of assembly language code.

u nt!KiSystemService L100

This will show me more code of the System Service Dispatch routine. But my objective is to view the last few instructions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> uf nt!KiSystemService

will try to disassemble just the function.

Answer (score 0):

on x86 `.fnent` will show function size / no of param it takes / no of locals 
size of prolog and offset start of function 
if the no function `does not have chunks` due to optimizations) 
you can simply start disassembling at ( offset start + size - X)

lkd> .fnent nt!NtCreateProcessEx
Debugger function entry 00ca5b70 for:
(805c73ea)   nt!NtCreateProcessEx   |  (805c7476)   nt!PsCreateSystemProcess
Exact matches:
    nt!NtCreateProcessEx =

OffStart:  000f03ea
ProcSize:  0x86
Prologue:  0xc
Params:    0n9 (0x24 bytes)
Locals:    0n7 (0x1c bytes)
Non-FPO

on `x64 FPO_DATA is not available instead IMAGE_FUNCTIOn_ENTRY` will be returned by .fnent 
you may need to look at the UnWind Inforamtion to get the details